# WPF Combo Box Not Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a combo box that is not binding at all. When the application runs nothing is populated into it. The data comes from a linq to sql class that I then roll into a custom list of objects. I can confirm that this list gets populated and at the appropriate time so it must be an issue with the binding. I am suspecting that data templates may be the way to go but truthfully am not sure how to apply that to this situation.

**Custom Object (Model)**

```
namespace IhsDataSync.Models.Config
{
    public class StoredActionsModel : BaseModel
    {
        private int _storedActionID;

        public int StoredActionID
        {
            get { return _storedActionID; }
            set { _storedActionID = value; OnPropertyChanged("StoredActionID"); }
        }

        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
        }

        private string _text;

        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); }
        }

        private bool _selected;

        public bool Selected
        {
            get { return _selected; }
            set { _selected = value; OnPropertyChanged("Selected"); }
        }



    }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public static List<StoredActionsModel> StoredActionsList = ActionLinq.buildStoredActions(); // Grabs list from data access layer

private List<StoredActionsModel> _storedActions = StoredActionsList;

    public List<StoredActionsModel> StoredActions
    {

        get { return _storedActions; }
        set {
            if (value != _storedActions)
            {
                _storedActions = value; OnPropertyChanged("StoredActions"); }
            }

    }
```

**buildStoredActions()**

```
public List<StoredActionsModel> buildStoredActions()
{
    List<StoredActionsModel> storedActions = new List<StoredActionsModel>();

    var sa = getStoredActions();

    foreach (var a in sa)
    {
        bool selected = false;
        if(a.Name == "Default Label"){
            selected = true;
        }

        storedActions.Add(new StoredActionsModel { StoredActionID = a.StoredActionID, Name = a.Name, Text = a.Text, Selected = selected });
    }

    return storedActions;
}
```

**xaml**

```
<ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="White" FontWeight="Bold" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= StoredActions.Text}" SelectedIndex="0">
```

Here ive told it to use the first item as selected. This was for testing to see if my initial binding works. Which as we know it doesn't.

Ultimately I would like the selected item to be determined by I a bool property on StoredActions called selected that i wish to use as at least the default selected item.

Can someone tell me why nothing is populating in my combo box in this example? Furthermore can someone help me take advantage of my selected property for selected item? Is this where a data template would come in?

p.s. Fairly new to wWPF and c# so i may need the 6 year old explanation of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StoredActions` is a `List`. It has no `Text` property. If it did, it would probably be a string, and you would be populating your combobox with the *characters* in that string. Not what you want.

You want to use `StoredActions` for your `ItemsSource`, so just do that.

I'm guessing your intent was something like "Display the Text properties of the StoredActions". If you want to display the `Text` property of each stored action, set the `DisplayMemberPath` property to `"Text"`. Then the combobox will take the `Text` property of each stored action, and use that for the display text.

```
<ComboBox 
    DisplayMemberPath="Text"
    ItemsSource="{Binding StoredActions}" 

    DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
    Background="White" 
    FontWeight="Bold" 
    SelectedIndex="0">
```

If this still doesn't work, we'll have to look at how you're setting your view's `DataContext`.

Now, if you want to do anything with the selection, here's how to approach that in proper MVVM fashion. Add this property to your viewmodel:

```
    private StoredActionsModel _selectedStoredAction;
    public StoredActionsModel SelectedStoredAction
    {
        get { return _selectedStoredAction; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedStoredAction)
            {
                _selectedStoredAction = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedStoredAction");
            }
        }
    }
```

And add a binding to it in the XAML like so:

```
<ComboBox 
    DisplayMemberPath="Text"
    ItemsSource="{Binding StoredActions}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStoredAction}"

    DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
    Background="White" 
    FontWeight="Bold" 
    SelectedIndex="0">
```

When the user selects an item in the combo, that will be assigned to the `SelectedStoredAction` property. You can add additional code to the setter on that property, or you can bind other control properties to it in the view.

Like so maybe:

```
private StoredActionsModel _selectedStoredAction;
public StoredActionsModel SelectedStoredAction
{
    get { return _selectedStoredAction; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _selectedStoredAction)
        {
            //  Unset Selected on old value, if there was one
            if (_selectedStoredAction != null)
            {
                _selectedStoredAction.Selected = false;
            }
            _selectedStoredAction = value;
            //  Set Selected on new value, if there is one
            if (_selectedStoredAction != null)
            {
                _selectedStoredAction.Selected = true;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedStoredAction");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right once again! Any thoughts as to how I can leverage my selected property on the StoredActions so that the initial selection is my Default and/or change that property to true or false respectively based on what has been selected? like an xaml element IsSelected = "Selected"

Comment: I have another one for you...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877466/wpf-change-window-layout-based-on-combo-box-selection-using-mvvm

Comment: @LCaraway Easy.